# Fechar Dialog aberto dentro do Adaptador do RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-recyclerview

Fiz um cabeçalho para meu `RecyclerView` que, quando clicado, abre um Dialog. Algum tempo depois, começou a dar esse erro:

```
Activity com.mypkg.myP has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44c46ff0 that was originally added here
05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity ccom.mypkg.myP has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44c46ff0 that was originally added here
05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:231)
05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
05-17 18:24:57.069: ERROR/WindowManager(18850):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
```

Vi [nesta publicação](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added) que isto seria resolvido fechando o Dialog na `onPause` ou `onDestroy`.

Como eu faço de dentro do adaptador?

Código que cria o `Dialog` no `Adapter`:

```
  public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof VHHeader) {
        final VHHeader VHheader = (VHHeader) holder;

VHheader.enviardica.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Dialog dpartilha = new Dialog(ctx);
                dpartilha.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

                dpartilha.setContentView(R.layout.partilha);

                LinearLayout laydicas = (LinearLayout) dpartilha.findViewById(R.id.laydicas);
                LinearLayout layeventos = (LinearLayout) dpartilha.findViewById(R.id.layeventos);

                dpartilha.show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não crie diálogos dentro de outras `View`s (como a `RecyclerView`). Deixe a `Activity` cuidar de exibir esse diálogo e de dispensá-lo quando for a hora, enquanto o `RecyclerView` apenas passa a mensagem pedindo para que o diálogo seja criado.

O jeito padrão de fazer isso sem aumentar o acoplamento é criar uma interface para a `Activity` implementar. Um exemplo:

Interface:

```
public interface ExibidorDeDialogoDePartilha {
    public void exibirDialogoDePartilha();
}
```

Activity:

```
public class MinhaActivity extends Activity implements ExibidorDeDialogoDePartilha {

    private AdapterDoMeuRecyclerView adapter;
    private Dialog dialogoDePartilha;

    @Override
    public void exibirDialogoDePartilha() {
       // Insira aqui o código de mostrar o diálogo
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.adapter = new AdapterDoMeuRecyclerView(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // Exemplo de código que dispensa o diálogo. Adapte às suas necessidades.
        if (dialogoDePartilha != null && dialogoDePartilha.isShowing()) {
            dialogoDePartilha.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

RecyclerView:

```
public class AdapterDoMeuRecyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterDoMeuRecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private ExibidorDeDialogoDePartilha exibidorDeDialogoDePartilha;

    public AdapterDoMeuRecyclerView(Context contexto) {
        try {
            this.exibidorDeDialogoDePartilha = (ExibidorDeDialogoDePartilha) contexto;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity ou Fragment que contém esse RecyclerView deve implementar ExibidorDeDialogoDePartilha.");
        }
    }

// .....

public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof VHHeader) {
        final VHHeader VHheader = (VHHeader) holder;

        VHheader.enviardica.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                exibidorDeDialogoDePartilha.exibirDialogoDePartilha();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Oi Pablo. Muito obrigada. Tentei fazer mas fiquei com uma dúvida - onde colocar o código da interface? Na activity ou abaixo? Obrigada!

Comment: Do jeito que eu fiz, ela estaria separada, em um novo arquivo Java, mas você pode colocar ela dentro do arquivo no qual está o Adapter e tirar o "public" (é o que eu costumo fazer).

Comment: Viu Pablo, e mais uma coisa. Estou fazendo praticamente tudo neste meu adaptador. Ele é do Recycler View da MainActivity. Isto serve para abrir Intents também ou isto não tem problema?

Comment: Do ponto de vista de separação de responsabilidades, talvez não seja o ideal, mas do ponto de vista de bugs, não tem problema, não.

Comment: Viu. Pablo me diz mas uma coisa, como eu estou iniciando activity dando clique no viewholdrer do adaptador. Existe alguma maneira de dar o finish ?

Comment: Precisa mesmo desse finish? Geralmente não é uma boa ideia encerrar uma Activity ao iniciar outra. Se acha que precisa mesmo, faça algo semelhante ao que fez para exibir o diálogo (criar uma interface, implementar o método na Activity etc.).